# What cleanup routines run when I terminate a running Linux process with a break?

Tags: c, linux, exit

Do cleanup routines registered with `atexit()` run when the program is terminated by sending a break ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to install handler for SIGINT signal.

Comment: How do I install a handler for this?

Comment: using `sigaction` or `signal` functions. But a signal handler cannot do arbitrary things (it could `siglongjmp`, or set a `volatile sigatomic_t` variable, etc. It can't `printf` or `malloc`)